# Find a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{12} \oplus \Bbb Z_{4} \oplus \Bbb Z_{15}$ of order $9$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{12} \oplus \Bbb Z_{4} \oplus \Bbb Z_{15}$ of order $9$.

I know that this group is non-cyclic, but I can't figure a way to even begin finding a subgroup of this order since $9$ doesn't divide $12, 4,$ or $15$ which implies there are no elements in any of the $\Bbb Z$'s whose order is $9$.

Comment: It's true 9 doesn't divide 12, 4, or 15.  But what is the order of $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{15}$?  It's not “12, 4, or 15”. :-)

Comment: Can you find two subgroups of order $3$? If so, try to see how to "combine" them to find a subgroup of order $9$.

Comment: @Bungo Interesting, I see that $\langle (4,0,0) \rangle \cup \langle (0,0,5) \rangle$ has $9$ elements.  Does this type of method usually work for finding subgroups or is it in this case simpler because of the small amount of combinations?

Comment: It generally works for subgroups of finitely generated abelian groups; for others, it's a trickier business.

Comment: @OliverG The key fact here is that in an **abelian** group, all subgroups are normal. Consequently the product $HK$ of any two subgroups $H$ and $K$ is itself a subgroup. So finding any two subgroups of order $3$ and forming their product gives you a subgroup of order $9$.

Answer (score 1):

How about $4\mathbb{Z}_{12}\oplus \{0\}\oplus 5\mathbb{Z}_{15}$? This group has $9$ elements. It doesn't matter that $9$ doesn't divide $12$, $4$, or $15$. $9$ must devide the order of the group, which is $12\cdot 4\cdot 15=720$.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $4\Bbb Z_{12} \oplus \{0\} \oplus 5\Bbb Z_{15}$?